# how to reach D5 in tuplesort.c 's polyphase merge algorithm?

Tags: sql, algorithm, postgresql

For studying polyphase merge algorithm of tuplesort.c, I use ddd and apend a table, which has a schema as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Towns (
    id SERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, -- Only unique inside a department
    article TEXT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL, -- Names are not really unique, for instance 'Sainte-Croix'
    department VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL REFERENCES Departments (code),
    UNIQUE (code, department)
    -- UNIQUE (name, department) -- Not perfectly unique but almost
);
```

and has 36684 records, and every record is like:

```
id          code  article  name      department

31800       266    \N    Machault    77
```

and for getting into external sort, I type the following command:

```
select * from towns order by name desc;
```

but I found it need not reach D5 and D6 during sorting,  I thought that the reason is the amount of runs is 3 (too small) before merging, for generate more runs, I shuffled the records when inputting them and got the same result.

so that I want some help, what schema and records do I as least need for reaching D5 and D6?  any advice will be appreciated!

Dillon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a very low value to `work_mem` to starve it of memory

```
set work_mem = 64;
```

64 KB is the minimum in 9.3. You may need to get a bigger data sample

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY

Comment: I tested it with work_mem=64 and got the same result, maybe I should test it using a bigger data sample, where I can get the ideal sample?

Comment: @abelard20008 You can generate it yourself using `generate_series` and `random`. Ask another question about it explaining that you need strings, numbers, the layout of the table.